# React-Native, problems importing and using ImageBackground

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm learning React Native and for one of my first apps, I want yo include a background image, so I include the `import {ImageBackground} from 'react-native'` to use it.

When I try to use it in my code, my android emulator launch this error:

**Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**

This is my entire code, as you can see, I don't have too much, so I don't know where is the problem.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Platform, View, Text, ImageBackground, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import {Button} from 'native-base'

var myImage = require('./assets/icon/landing.jpg')

export default class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source = {myImage} style = {styles.bgImage}>
          <Text>The button is right bellow</Text>
          <Button><Text>Hello World</Text></Button>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  container: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 24 : 0
  },
  bgImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

I try to follow the documentation of React Native from their official page but I can't see the error: *https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground#__docusaurus*

I'm using expo to generate the project.

Answer (score 0):

Per the react-native `ImageBackground` documentation, you must set specify some width and height attributes for the `ImageBackground` to work.

[image]

Comment: Following the documentation, I try with `resizeMode: 'cover'` (like in the example) and doesn't work. I just update my post right now.

Answer (score 0):

This error does not seem to be caused by ImageBackground. Checking your code out I realized you are trying to use StyleSheet but forgot to import it from react-native.

Try this:

```
import {Platform, View, Text, ImageBackground, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      borderWidth: 1,
      flex: 1,
      marginTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 24 : 0
    }
});
```

Comment: Hm, that's true. But I just included right now following your answer, and still not working. I'm going to update the post.

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked fine but I'm not using expo.

Comment: Try to rebuild your app!

Comment: That could be an option, but honestly, I don't know how to create a React Native project without expo, I was following a Udemy's course hehe. I'll search for it, thank you so much!

Comment: Man that's very easy. Try follow this https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.60/getting-started. If you have any question I can hekp you. Text me on linkedin www.linkedin.com/in/edilsonlimaa/